# How to get the source name of a feature layer

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have feature layers that have a different name in the TOC then that they do in the GDB. I cannot change either of these and I need the name of the feature class from the GDB in order to make my model work. I have tried things such as parse path but I only get the name of the layer as it is in the TOC.

I have tried a few ArcPy/Python methods, but with my little knowledge of these things, I could not figure out how to get the GDB name as an output parameter.

I am using ArcMap version 10.3.1

Below I have added an example of my model and the code I last used to try and get the name.

[image: Example of model]

```
import os
import arcpy

layer = arcpy.GetParameter(0)

print(os.path.basename(layer))
```

Comment: `arcpy.Describe(lyr).name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to treat a spatial dataset as if it is a normal file so you are accessing properties that are not appropriate (i.e. `os.path.basename`).
I would use the Calculate value tool but you could easily adapt your existing script if you wish.

[image: Model]

The Calculate value tool is set up as:

[image: Tool]

You would change the parameter highlighted in red to what every you are using, don't ignore the quotes around it.